# JFrame always focused

Tags: java, swing, jframe, focus

I have a Java-application that needs to be brought to the foreground and you have to be able to press keys.

I thought about a timer. It's like you can play a game and press some keys and the timer will count.

I've got this

```
@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Lost");
    TimerFrame.toFront();
    TimerFrame.requestFocus();
}
```

It's flashing in the taskbar and not focused all the time.

Comment: possible with JDialog, but JDialog can't be in TaskBar

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this reliably, because its considered malicious behavior by the window manager.

There were all kinds of crapwares doing *just that*, so at some point (starting with WindowsXP IIRC) some additional checks were added to the window system to prevent popups stealing the input focus.

While you may find a way around the current restrictions in the window manager, you should think *hard* if that "feature" will accomplish anything other than annoying users.

Here's the perfect example of that kind: [Frame always on top of my program only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361899)